# Google Play Books, creating desktop links to books, and opening them

Tags: bookmarks, ebooks, google-play-books

I would like to know whether it is possible to place a link to a Google Play book on the Android desktop, and click on it to open the Google Play book and read it.

How may I accomplish this behavior.

It would be even be nice if I could organize book links in folders.

Thank you.